# input onChange function not being called when value changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, jsx

I have two text areas, the first one's onChange function works perfectly as the user types into it.

The second one receives it's value from a variable, and doesn't call the onChange function when the variable changes.

Here are my inputs (jsx):

Working:

```
        <input
          value={inputValue}
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
```

Not working:

```
        <input
          value={transcript}
          onChange={onInputChange}
        />
```

`onInputChange` just calls `setInputValue(event.target.value);`

`inputValue` is of course the state

`transcript` is the changing variable (lets say it changes on button click)

What I'm asking is: is it possible to force an onChange event to fire, or preferably, have the onChange event fire when the value changes.

Comment: Changing a variable doesn't trigger a render (and depending on where it's declared in your component it may not even be holding a value), but without more context there is no way to offer more concrete help.

Answer (score -1):

you want to use `onchange` not `onChange` like you have it now.

```js
const onInputChange = (input) => {
  alert(input.value);
}
```

```html
<input value="Change Me" onchange="onInputChange(this)"/>
```

Comment: This is a jsx element, so onChange is correct